# I am trying to install home brew on my terminal but i also get this error below

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew

it seems to be a problem  relating to GitHub.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)" curl:
```

`(7) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Connection refused`

Comment: Do you control the network you are on?  What firewall is between you and the internet?  What filtering software is running on the Mac you are trying to install on?

Comment: I was using a VPN. i switched it off but i still got thesame error. @MarcWilson

Comment: Can you access GitHub.com in your browser?

Comment: @JBallin yes, I can

Comment: Without the VPN, what is between you and raw.githubusercontent.com ?  Can you hit the given URL with a web broser and display the script?

Comment: @MarcWilson Only a WiFi connection to the internet.   the URL returns *404: Not Found*

Comment: @MarcWilson now it returns this on the command_line *subsh dquote>*

Answer (score -1):

[This answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59572626/curl-7-failed-to-connect-to-raw-githubusercontent-com-port-443-connection-re) suggests to "Set your DNS Server to 8.8.8.8". It worked for me and I assume it is an error relating to your network configuration rather than github.

If you are in mainland China, you could [try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy) for configuring a proxy for github.

Comment: Why does that work?

Comment: its not working @mmmmmm

Comment: I expected that it would not - @ivorhoulker needs to explain why they think it works (I have downvoted the SO answer)

Comment: @mmmmmm Probably the assumption that one DNS will return a different set of IP's from the rotation than another.   It looks like there are four nodes behind that name.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced a similar error while installing brew on my mac book pro. It is all because of firewall blocking in your network.

Try changing to the new network connection. It will help you!

Comment: Can you explain this some? How does changing your network connection resolve this problem or even get around a firewall?